# Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime-in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, datepart

I've ready as many answers to this problem as I could, but cannot come up with the solution.

We recently moved our application from SQL 2008 to 2012.  This worked without a problem in 2008.

I'm only going to add parts of the SP where I think the error exists in, I get the above error message when running this stored procedure with 2014-02-01 for @startdate, and 2014-02-28 for @enddate.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Action_UpdateRProfitabilityReportTable9-21-09]
@startdate datetime,
@enddate datetime,
@vehiclemaintence float,
@fleetops float,
@driverrate float,
@helperrate float,
@fuelrate float

AS



INSERT INTO [dbo].[rprofitabilityreport]

(Route, Material, Helper, monthofyear, monthyear, sitecount, totalstops , RecurringRevenue, WORevenue, DumpTons, DumpFees,
FuelPumped, Miles, TotalHours, FuelCosts, VehicleMaintence, FleetOPs, LaborCosts,
BenefitFactor, ActualDumpRate, RouteExpenses, RouteExpensesperStop, CardboardDump, MixPaperDump) 




left join (select distinct sh.route, sh.routemonth, sh.monthyr, count(sh.siteid) AS SiteCount
from (select sh.siteid, sh.route, datepart(mm,sh.servicedate) AS RouteMonth, left(cast(datepart(yyyy, sh.servicedate) as varchar(4)),4) + '-' + right('00' + cast(datepart(mm, sh.servicedate) as varchar(2)),2) AS MonthYR, count(sh.servicehistoryuid) As RouteCount
from [dbo].[ServiceHistory_vw_With_ServiceUID] sh
where sh.servicedate between @startdate and @enddate
group by sh.siteid, sh.route, datepart(mm,sh.servicedate), datepart(yyyy, sh.servicedate)) as sh
group by sh.route, sh.routemonth, sh.monthyr) rc ON rc.route = a1.route and rc.monthyr = a1.monthyr) RS
```

Comment: This error appears because somewhere in here you have an implicit conversion to a datetime datatype and some value in the table is not a valid datetime string representation. This is why you should ALWAYS use the datetime datatypes for storing this type of data. When you store dates as varchar this message will show up at some point and drive you crazy. You have a number of datetime columns. It is in one of those columns in one of those tables. About the only to find it is trial and error casting each of those columns one at a time.

Comment: February 28th eh?  Could there be some weird addy or subtracty date logic being affected by leap years (or lack thereof)?

Comment: You could also copy/paste the entire query part of the SP into a separate query window, setup your vars appropriately, and potentially get a much better idea of where the error is occurring... at least i usually have better luck pinpointing SP issues when running the queries behind the SP rather than the SP itself

Comment: I ran the query part of the script, substituting values for variables and got the error "error converting data type varchar to numeric"  This is probably telling me that the insert part of the SP is failing because of that error.  Any ideas where to look next?

Comment: You haven't really posted us the insert statement only a partial of it, so kind of hard to say.  a sqlfiddle would be most useful with the table schemas and sample data but that might be a lot of info to mock up